# Formula in Theory of Complex Spectra. II of Giulio Racah

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum

In this article [Theory of Complex Spectra II](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRev.62.438) Giulio Racah defines $f(m_{1} m_{2} ; jm)$ by
\begin{multline}
\left(m_{1} m_{2} \mid j m\right)
=(-1)^{j_{1}-m_{1}} f\left(m_{1} m_{2} ; j m\right)\left[\left(j_{1}+m_{1}\right) !\left(j_{2}+m_{2}\right) !(j+m) !\right]^{\frac{1}{2}} /\left[\left(j_{1}-m_{1}\right) !\left(j_{2}-m_{2}\right) !(j-m) !\right]^{\frac{1}{2}}
\end{multline}
where $\left(m_{1} m_{2} \mid j m\right)$ are the Clebsch-Gordan coefficients.Then, he shows that
\begin{multline}
f\left(m_{1} m_{2} ; j m-1\right)=\\ \left(j_{2}+m_{2}+1\right)\left(j_{2}-m_{2}\right) f\left(m_{1} m_{2}+1 ; j m\right)-\\ \left(j_{1}+m_{1}+1\right)\left(j_{1}-m_{1}\right) f\left(m_{1}+1 m_{2} ; j m\right) \tag{1}
\end{multline}
Now he claims that
\begin{multline}
 f\left(m_{1} m_{2} ; j m\right)=f\left(m_{1} m_{2} ; j j -u\right)=\\ A_{j} \sum_{t}(-1)^{t}\left(\begin{array}{l}
u \\
t
\end{array}\right)  \frac{\left(j_{1}+m_{1}+t\right) !\left(j_{1}-m_{1}\right) !\left(j_{2}+m_{2}+u-t\right) !\left(j_{2}-m_{2}\right) !}{\left(j_{1}+m_{1}\right) !\left(j_{1}-m_{1}-t\right) !\left(j_{2}+m_{2}\right) !\left(j_{2}-m_{2}-u+t\right) !}
\tag{2}\end{multline}
The summation parameter takes on all integral values consistent
with the factorial notation, the factorial of a negative number being meaningless.To demonstrate (2) he says that it suffices to verify that it satisfies (1).
This what I tried.We have that
\begin{multline}
\left(j_{1}+m_{1}+1\right)\left(j_{1}-m_{1}\right) f\left(m_{1}+1 m_{2} ; j m\right)=\\ A_{j} \sum_{t}(-1)^{t}\left(\begin{array}{l}
u \\
t
\end{array}\right) \left(j_{1}-m_{1}-t\right)\left(j_{1}+m_{1}+1+t\right) \times \\ \frac{\left(j_{1}+m_{1}+t\right) !\left(j_{1}-m_{1}\right) !\left(j_{2}+m_{2}+u-t\right) !\left(j_{2}-m_{2}\right) !}{\left(j_{1}+m_{1}\right) !\left(j_{1}-m_{1}-t\right) !\left(j_{2}+m_{2}\right) !\left(j_{2}-m_{2}-u+t\right) !}
\end{multline}

\begin{multline}
\left(j_{2}+m_{2}+1\right)\left(j_{2}-m_{2}\right) f\left(m_{1} m_{2} +1 ; j m\right)=\\ A_{j} \sum_{t}(-1)^{t}\left(\begin{array}{l}
u \\
t
\end{array}\right) \left(j_{2}-m_{2}-u+t\right)\left(j_{2}+m_{2}+1+u -t \right) \times \\ \frac{\left(j_{1}+m_{1}+t\right) !\left(j_{1}-m_{1}\right) !\left(j_{2}+m_{2}+u-t\right) !\left(j_{2}-m_{2}\right) !}{\left(j_{1}+m_{1}\right) !\left(j_{1}-m_{1}-t\right) !\left(j_{2}+m_{2}\right) !\left(j_{2}-m_{2}-u+t\right) !}
\end{multline}

and
\begin{multline}
 f\left(m_{1} m_{2}; j m-1\right)=\\ A_{j} \sum_{t}(-1)^{t}\left(\begin{array}{l}
u \\
t
\end{array}\right) \times \\  \frac{u+1}{u+1-t}\left(j_{2}+m_{2}+u+1-t\right)\left(j_{2}-m_{2}-u+t\right) \times \\ \frac{\left(j_{1}+m_{1}+t\right) !\left(j_{1}-m_{1}\right) !\left(j_{2}+m_{2}+u-t\right) !\left(j_{2}-m_{2}\right) !}{\left(j_{1}+m_{1}\right) !\left(j_{1}-m_{1}-t\right) !\left(j_{2}+m_{2}\right) !\left(j_{2}-m_{2}-u+t\right) !}
\end{multline}
and so we arrive at the following
\begin{multline}
 \frac{(j_{1}+m_{1}+u+1)!(j_{1}-m_{1})!}{(j_{1}-m_{1}-u-1)!(j_{1}+m_{1})!}A_{j}(-1)^{u+1}+\\ A_{j} \sum_{t}(-1)^{t}\left(\begin{array}{l}
u \\
t
\end{array}\right)  \frac{\left(j_{1}+m_{1}+t\right) !\left(j_{1}-m_{1}\right) !\left(j_{2}+m_{2}+u-t\right) !\left(j_{2}-m_{2}\right) !}{\left(j_{1}+m_{1}\right) !\left(j_{1}-m_{1}-t\right) !\left(j_{2}+m_{2}\right) !\left(j_{2}-m_{2}-u+t\right) !}\times \\ 
\Bigg[  \frac{u+1}{u+1-t}\left(j_{2}+m_{2}+u+1-t\right)\left(j_{2}-m_{2}-u+t\right)+\left(j_{1}-m_{1}-t\right)\left(j_{1}+m_{1}+1+t\right) \\-\left(j_{2}-m_{2}-u+t\right)\left(j_{2}+m_{2}+1+u -t \right) \Bigg] =0   /tag{3}
\end{multline}

where $m=m_1+m_2$ , $u=j-m$ and $j=j_1+j_2$

Now $j_1-m_1=j_1-(m-m_2)=j_1-(j-u-m_2)=-j_2+m_2+u$
and  so
$-\left(j_{1}-m_{1}-t\right)=(j_2 -m_2-u +t)$

After some algebra last equation becomes
\begin{multline}
\frac{(j_{1}+m_{1}+u+1)!(j_{1}-m_{1})!}{(j_{1}-m_{1}-u-1)!(j_{1}+m_{1})!}A_{j}(-1)^{u+1}+ \\ A_{j} \sum_{t}(-1)^{t}\left(\begin{array}{l}
u \\
t
\end{array}\right)  \frac{\left(j_{1}+m_{1}+t\right) !\left(j_{1}-m_{1}\right) !\left(j_{2}+m_{2}+u-t\right) !\left(j_{2}-m_{2}\right) !}{\left(j_{1}+m_{1}\right) !\left(j_{1}-m_{1}-t\right) !\left(j_{2}+m_{2}\right) !\left(j_{2}-m_{2}-u+t\right) !}\times \\ 
(j_2 -m_2-u +t)\Bigg[  \frac{u+1}{u+1-t}\left(j_{2}+m_{2}\right) -j-m-1 \Bigg] =0 
\end{multline}

Can anyone tell why this last expression is zero?

Comment: Would this fit better on Math.SE?

Comment: What is youe question? The algera derivation between the last two equation?

Comment: My question is why the last expression is zero

Comment: It is derived from the previous equation, and the previous one is zero as well. I still cannot get your meaning.

Comment: I am trying to proof that the previous equation is zero

Comment: The aim is too proof that (2) is true. To do that we have to show that the (3) is zero

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Staring from the given definition of $ f(m_{1}, m_{2} ; j ,m)$:
\begin{multline} \tag{1}
 f(m_{1}, m_{2} ; j ,m)=f(m_{1}, m_{2} ; j, j -u)=\\
  A_{j} \sum_{t}(-1)^{t}
  \left(  \begin{array}{l}
u \\
t
\end{array} \right)
  \frac{(j_{1}+m_{1}+t) ! (j_{1}-m_{1}) ! (j_{2}+m_{2}+u-t) ! (j_{2}-m_{2}) !}{(j_{1}+m_{1}) ! (j_{1}-m_{1}-t) ! (j_{2}+m_{2}) ! (j_{2}-m_{2}-u+t) !}
\end{multline}

We are aiming at proving the following equation:
\begin{multline}\tag{2}
f(m_{1}, m_{2} ; j, m-1)=\\ (j_{2}+m_{2}+1) (j_{2}-m_{2})  f(m_{1} ,m_{2}+1 ; j ,m)-\\
 (j_{1}+m_{1}+1) (j_{1}-m_{1}) f(m_{1}+1, m_{2} ; j ,m) 
 \end{multline}

**PROOF**

First write down the left-hand-side of the equation (2), defining $u_1 \equiv j -m +1$.:
\begin{multline}\tag{3}
f(m_{1}, m_{2} ; j, m-1)=\\
  A_{j} \sum_{t}(-1)^{t}
  \left(  \begin{array}{l}
u_1 \\
t
\end{array} \right)
  \frac{(j_{1}+m_{1}+t) ! (j_{1}-m_{1}) ! (j_{2}+m_{2}+u_1-t) ! (j_{2}-m_{2}) !}{(j_{1}+m_{1}) ! (j_{1}-m_{1}-t) ! (j_{2}+m_{2}) ! (j_{2}-m_{2}-u_1+t) !},
 \end{multline}

Then, examine the two terms in the right-ahnd-side, using $u_2 \equiv j -m = u_1 - 1$. The frist term in the RHS:
\begin{multline}\tag{4}
 (j_{2}+m_{2}+1) (j_{2}-m_{2})  f(m_{1} ,m_{2}+1 ; j ,m) =  (j_{2}+m_{2}+1) (j_{2}-m_{2}) \times\\
  A_{j} \sum_{t}(-1)^{t}
  \left(  \begin{array}{l}
u_2 \\
t
\end{array} \right)
  \frac{(j_{1}+m_{1}+t) ! (j_{1}-m_{1}) ! (j_{2}+m_{2}+1+u_2-t) ! (j_{2}-m_{2}-1) !}{(j_{1}+m_{1}) ! (j_{1}-m_{1}-t) ! (j_{2}+m_{2}+1) ! (j_{2}-m_{2}-1-u_2+t) !}\\
=  A_{j} \sum_{t}(-1)^{t}
  \left(  \begin{array}{l}
u_2 \\
t
\end{array} \right)
  \frac{(j_{1}+m_{1}+t) ! (j_{1}-m_{1}) ! (j_{2}+m_{2}+1+u_2-t) ! (j_{2}-m_{2}) !}{(j_{1}+m_{1}) ! (j_{1}-m_{1}-t) ! (j_{2}+m_{2}) ! (j_{2}-m_{2}-1-u_2+t) !}
 \end{multline}
The two multipliers are combined into the factorial functions in Eq.(4).

The second term in the RHS:
\begin{multline}\tag{5}
 (j_{1}+m_{1}+1) (j_{1}-m_{1})  f(m_{1}+1 ,m_{2} ; j ,m) =  (j_1+m_1+1) (j_1-m_1) \times\\
  A_{j} \sum_{t}(-1)^{t}
  \left(  \begin{array}{l}
u_2 \\
t
\end{array} \right)
  \frac{(j_{1}+m_{1}+1+t) ! (j_{1}-m_{1}-1) ! (j_{2}+m_{2}+u_2-t) ! (j_{2}-m_{2}) !}{(j_{1}+m_{1}+1) ! (j_{1}-m_{1}-1-t) ! (j_{2}+m_{2}) ! (j_{2}-m_{2}-u_2+t) !}\\
=    A_{j} \sum_{t}(-1)^{t}
  \left(  \begin{array}{l}
u_2 \\
t
\end{array} \right)
  \frac{(j_{1}+m_{1}+1+t) ! (j_{1}-m_{1}) ! (j_{2}+m_{2}+u_2-t) ! (j_{2}-m_{2}) !}{(j_{1}+m_{1}) ! (j_{1}-m_{1}-1-t) ! (j_{2}+m_{2}) ! (j_{2}-m_{2}-u_2+t) !}
 \end{multline}
The two multipliers are also combined into the factorial functions in Eq.(5).

```
Now we will proceed to show that Eq.(4)-Eq.(5) = Eq.(3).
```

In Eq.(5), we change the summation dummy index $t+1 = t'$.
\begin{multline}\tag{6}
 A_{j} \sum_{t'=1}^{t'=u_2+1} (-1)^{t'-1}
  \left(  \begin{array}{l}
u_2 \\
t'-1
\end{array} \right)
  \frac{(j_{1}+m_{1}+t') ! (j_{1}-m_{1}) ! (j_{2}+m_{2}+u_2-t'+1) ! (j_{2}-m_{2}) !}{(j_{1}+m_{1}) ! (j_{1}-m_{1}-t') ! (j_{2}+m_{2}) ! (j_{2}-m_{2}-u_2+t'-1) !} \\
  =    A_{j} \sum_{t'=0}^{t'=u_1} (-1)^{t'-1}
  \left(  \begin{array}{l}
u_2 \\
t'-1
\end{array} \right)
  \frac{(j_{1}+m_{1}+t') ! (j_{1}-m_{1}) ! (j_{2}+m_{2}+u_1-t') ! (j_{2}-m_{2}) !}{(j_{1}+m_{1}) ! (j_{1}-m_{1}-t') ! (j_{2}+m_{2}) ! (j_{2}-m_{2}-u_1+t') !} 
 \end{multline}
In the last expression, we use $u_2 = j-m = u_1 - 1$, and extend the summation lower limit from $1$ to $0$, since the term $t'=0$ vanishes having $(-1)!$ in the denominator of the combinatory function.

Also in Eq.(4), we replace $u_2 +1 = u_1$, and extended the summation upper limit from $u_2$ to $u_1 = u_2 +1$, the extra term has a $-1 !$ in the denominator of the combinatory function, thus vanishes.
\begin{multline}\tag{7}
  A_{j} \sum_{t=0}^{t=u_1} (-1)^{t}
  \left(  \begin{array}{l}
u_2 \\
t
\end{array} \right)
  \frac{(j_{1}+m_{1}+t) ! (j_{1}-m_{1}) ! (j_{2}+m_{2}+u_1-t) ! (j_{2}-m_{2}) !}{(j_{1}+m_{1}) ! (j_{1}-m_{1}-t) ! (j_{2}+m_{2}) ! (j_{2}-m_{2} -u_1+t) !}
 \end{multline}

```
Finally, the Eq.(4) - Eq.(5) now becomes Eq.(7) - Eq.(6):
```

\begin{multline}\tag{8}
  \text{Eq.(7) } - \text{ Eq.(6) } = A_{j} \sum_{t=0}^{t=u_1} (-1)^{t}
  \left\{
  \left(  \begin{array}{l}
u_2 \\
t
\end{array} \right) - (-1)
 \left(  \begin{array}{l}
u_2 \\
t-1
\end{array} \right)
\right\} \times \\
  \frac{(j_{1}+m_{1}+t) ! (j_{1}-m_{1}) ! (j_{2}+m_{2}+u_1-t) ! (j_{2}-m_{2}) !}{(j_{1}+m_{1}) ! (j_{1}-m_{1}-t) ! (j_{2}+m_{2}) ! (j_{2}-m_{2} -u_1+t) !}
 \end{multline}

Evaluate the combinatroy functions in the curry braket:
\begin{multline} \tag{9}
  \left(  \begin{array}{l}
u_2 \\
t
\end{array} \right) +
 \left(  \begin{array}{l}
u_2 \\
t-1
\end{array} \right)
= \frac{u_2 !}{t! (u_2-t)!} +  \frac{u_2 !}{(t-1)! (u_2 - t + 1)!} \\
=  \frac{u_2 !}{t! (u_2-t+1)!} \left(  u_2 - t + 1 + t\right)  =  \frac{(u_2+1) !}{t! (u_2-t+1)!} = \frac{(u_1) !}{t! (u_1-t)!}
=   \left(  \begin{array}{l}
u_1 \\
t
\end{array} \right)
 \end{multline}

Using the result of Eq.(9), Eq.(8) becomes:
\begin{multline}\tag{10}
  A_{j} \sum_{t=0}^{t=u_1} (-1)^{t}
 \left(  \begin{array}{l}
u_1 \\
t
\end{array} \right)
  \frac{(j_{1}+m_{1}+t) ! (j_{1}-m_{1}) ! (j_{2}+m_{2}+u_1-t) ! (j_{2}-m_{2}) !}{(j_{1}+m_{1}) ! (j_{1}-m_{1}-t) ! (j_{2}+m_{2}) ! (j_{2}-m_{2} -u_1+t) !}
 \end{multline}

Eq. (10) is exactly the same as Eq.(3), the left hand side of Eq.(2). Therfore Eq.(4) - Eq.(5) = Eq.(3), conclude the proof of the equality in Eq.(2).

Comment: Thank you for your response.